# npm install -g appium not working

Tags: android, node.js, npm, appium, selenium-grid

I'm trying to set up `Appium` on my `Mac Os`. My goal is to run Appium server nodes to use multiple tests on multiple devices Android ( VM ).
I installed it using the **.dmg file** on the Appium website, but now, I need to create nodes to run multiple tests on multiple devices ( Android ). To do this, I need to use the " appium " command in the terminal so I try this :

```
  > brew install node      
     > npm install -g appium  
     > npm install wd         
     > appium &               
     > node your-appium-test.js
```

Everything was fine until " `npm install -g appium`  ". The command runs but I've got an error at the end of the installation :

> 9 errors generated.

```
  make: *** [Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o] Error 1
     gyp ERR! build error
     gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
     gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
     gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
     gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
     gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
     gyp ERR! System Darwin 14.3.0
     gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.6.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
     gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Max/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
     gyp ERR! node -v v5.6.0
     gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
     gyp ERR! not ok
     npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.1.0 utf-8-validate@1.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
     npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.1.0 Exit status 1
     /Users/Max/.npm-packages/lib
      └── appium@1.4.16
```

And after that I can't run my " appium & " command, getting this error

```
  appium &
  [1] 9592
  Mac$ -bash: appium: command not found
```

Any idea of my problem? Or know a way to run multiple devices test with Appium and Selenium Grid?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need install XCode7 as mention at [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/734)